# How do I make a root-only shell command executable by normal users

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to run the `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/bind` and its companion `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/unbind` from a Python script WITHOUT touching the `sudoers` file.

The main issues is that I can't use `sudo` from the Python script, so I need to make bind/unbind runnable by the normal user (I can't run the Python script as root either).

Update: I created a group, added the normal user and root to that group and did

```
chmod root:mygroup
```

The commands I want to access without having to use sudo or provide a password are:

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

They have the following permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root mygroup  # (for bind)
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root mygroup  # (for unbind)
```

Also, the folders leading up to the two programs/commands (namely /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/) have this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root
```

I still get "permission denied" but if I **keep all configurations plus a `chmod 777**` on the bind and unbind files it works, where is my error?

Comment: Create a setuid wrapper.

Comment: ...see [setuid setgid wrapper for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541427/setuid-setgid-wrapper-for-python-script) for an example of someone else doing that.

Comment: Do I need to use C for this? Can't I do it from Python?

Comment: You need to use C, or some other language that compiles to a binary executable. Operating systems following modern security practices don't honor the setuid bit on scripts.

Comment: Remove the write bit for world from those executables. Never set permissions to 777!

Comment: Did your normal user log out and back in after you added them to the group?

Comment: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364), [How can I use SetUID on a shell script to run as a non-root user?](https://serverfault.com/q/397969), [Why do my setuid root bash shell scripts not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33565729/608639), [setuid/setgid wrapper for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24541427/608639), [Setuid bit on python script : Linux vs Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8314012/608639), [How to set the setuid bit in a program of a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9536846/608639) and friends.

Comment: Alright, a small update: setuid is out of the question since I can't use compiled languages. Also, I tried Dennis Williamson's suggestions but turns out the permissions and ownerships for those two binaries ARE BEING RESET ON REBOOT.